# Is there an algorithm to average using different constraints on data?

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, matrix-multiplication, linear-equation

| Month | Product | Product | Product | Current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y |  | A | 17 |
| 2 | Y |  | A | 22 |
| 3 | Y |  | A | 21 |
| 4 | **Y** | **S** | **Q** | **44** |
| 5 | Y | S | Q | 32 |
| 6 | Y | S | Q | 23 |
| 7 | Y | S | B | 56 |
| 8 | Y | S | B | 73 |
| 9 | Y | S | B | 12 |
| 10 | Y |  | C | 26 |
| 11 | Y |  | C | 45 |
| 12 | Y |  | C | 37 |

As seen in table above I have some data, elements of which form part of different products. For example, 4th element in above table (highlighted row) i.e, `44` is part of product `Q`, `S` and `Y`.
Each product has an average as below :

```
average of Product A=(17+22+21)/3=20
average of Product Q=(44+32+23)/3=33
average of Product S=(44+32+23+56+73+12)/6=40
average of Product Y=(17+22+21+44+32+23+56+73+12+26+45+37)/12=34
```

Now I want to manipulate the data such that new averages are:

```
Average of product A=   25
Average of product Q =  35
Average of Product S=   32
Average of product Y=   39
```

and shape of months within a product should be maintained.

So result should be (example calculation):

```
new Month 1= (new average - current average) +current month 1 value
new Month 1= (25 - 20) + 17 = 22

new Month 2= (new average - current average) +current month 2 value
new month 2 = (25 - 20 ) + 22 = 27

new Month 3= (new average - current average) +current month 3 value
new months 3 =(25-20)+ 21= 26
```

**monthly shape difference example**

| month | month 1 | month 2 | month 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| current | 17 | 22 | 21 |
| current monthly difference |  | 22-17=**5** | 21-22=**-1** |
| New | 22 | 27 | 26 |
| New monthly difference |  | 27-22=**5** | 26-27=**-1** |

It can see that `month 2 - month1` for both current and new data is `5` and `month 3- month 2` is `-1` for both current and new data. Hence, monthly shape for product `A` is maintained.

| Month | Product | Product | Product | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y |  | A | 22 |
| 2 | Y |  | A | 27 |
| 3 | Y |  | A | 26 |
| 4 | Y | S | Q | 46 |
| 5 | Y | S | Q | 34 |
| 6 | Y | S | Q | 25 |
| 7 | Y | S | B | 38 |
| 8 | Y | S | B | 55 |
| 9 | Y | S | B | -6 |
| 10 | Y |  | C | 57 |
| 11 | Y |  | C | 76 |
| 12 | Y |  | C | 68 |

Currently I have a VBA code that loops over each element multiple times to calculate difference between current and new averages and apply this difference to elements.
Is there any matrix algorithm I can use that would make the same calculations instead of using iterative loops ? Algorithm code will be implemented in Matlab, C++ or Python or VBA.
Currently I have been exploring MATLAB function [`lsqlin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) but cannot get it to do what I want.

Could you please help?

Comment: What operations are you allowed on the table? Can you add rows? Remove rows? Change the "current" field in a row? Change the "product" fields in a row?

Comment: Addition or subtraction of what?

Comment: What is the relevance of the original data in the "current" column? Why not start with an empty column and just determine the values  for getting the desired averages?

Comment: @Stef as long as the end result is the same as posted, any operations can be used.  shape of each month in "current" column within a product needs to be maintained in "new column".  so essentially "new" column (result) is just a scaled up version of "current" column.

Comment: You have a system of 4 linear equations with 12 variables. Just find any solution to that; there are infinitely many.

Comment: I don't really understand those requirements. What does "same as posted" mean? Is the example you gave the unique and only solution? How did you arrive to that solution? What does "shape of each month in current column within a product" mean?

Comment: @trincot to give it a real world context, "current" column are monthly forward prices from yesterday. But today only product averages of month is available to me and that has changed from yesterday. So I need to create new monthly forward price curve based on new averages while maintaining the monthly shape of the product.

Comment: 'Monthly shape'?

Comment: Note that the example you gave has 12 lines and 5 columns, so most likely no one is going to study it very attentively to try to reverse-engineer your transformation and come up with a formula. You'll have to describe your requirements with words we can understand. So far it's very unclear what "monthly shape" means.

Comment: @Stef thanks, I understand your point.                                                                                     It can be seen that month 2 - month1 for both current and new data is 5 and month 3- month 2 is -1 for both current and new data. Hence, monthly shape for product A is maintained as difference between months for current and new data is same.   I have edited the question with a table to explain it better. please let me know if it's still not clear. thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @trincot added a table in question to explain better

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hi, solution is unique as monthly differences in each product A,Q,B and C have to be same in "current" and "new" data.

Comment: So then you have more linear equations in your system - some of the form `m1 + m2 + m3 = 25*3` to reflect desired averages, and others of the form `m2 - m1 = 5` to reflect fixed deltas. Collect all those equations, then solve the resulting system for `m_i`.

Comment: I noticed the "linear-equation" tag.. but your equation is not linear. "Y+A" yields 3 different answers : "22 or 27 or 26" (similar to others) | If the Y distribution per month is different, should we assume the Y distribution for month 1-3 is the same as other months?

Answer (score 0):

### The method :

1. Ignore individual month value, view it as a sum (that relates to its shape). [ mth1-mth12 >> a-d ]
2. Write all needed relation. [ avg_X <--> a,b,c,d ]
3. Using the relation & new known value, solve for the sum [ a,b,c,d ]

### Implementation :

Step1 : line 1-4 | Step2 : line 5-8

Defining :

| Value & relation | "Current" case | "new" case |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a = sum(mth1,mth2,mth3) | 60 | ? |
| b = sum(mth4,mth5,mth6) | 99 | ? |
| c = sum(mth7,mth8,mth9) | 141 | ? |
| d = sum(mth10,mth11,mth12) | 108 | ? |
| avg_A = a/3 | 20 | 25 |
| avg_Q = b/3 | 33 | 35 |
| avg_S = (b+c)/6 | 40 | 32 |
| avg_Y = (a+b+c+d)/12 | 34 | 39 |

In "Current" case : all variable above have defined values.

In "new" case (Step3) :

```
 avg_A = a/3 = 25 >> a = 25*3 = 75
 avg_Q = b/3 = 35 >> b = 35*3 = 105
 avg_S = (b+c)/6 = ((105)+c)/6 = 32 >> c = 32*6-105 = 87
 avg_Y = (a+b+c+d)/12 = ((75)+(105)+(87)+d)/12 = 39 >> d = 201
```

Fill in mth1-12 with any value that can produce a,b,c,d value above.

Done.

p/s: since OP only share 1 new "case", Step2 detail may varies. However, at least for this "shapes", this works.

<sub>My comment earlier actually in point to a statement "since the (observed relation is not really linear, a matrix cannot be built on the original table". Nevertheless, if you can figure out how to solve/put the Step2 relations in matrix form, step3 should be easier/automated.</sub>